# Creating a Heat map (2D Histogram) in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am teaching myself D3. My goal is to create a drop down menu where a person can pick a name and what gets returned is a heat map with that person's spending habit (please tell me if I am getting too ambitious with D3 here, I honestly do not know). I created a dummy TSV (spending.tsv) file with the format (name,month number (mnum), year, spent).

```
name    mnum    year    spent
Jane    1   2010    10
Jane    2   2010    20
Jane    3   2010    30.54
Jane    4   2010    67.84
Jane    5   2010    100
Jane    6   2010    110.87
Jane    7   2010    58
Jane    8   2010    70
Jane    9   2010    68.91
Jane    10  2010    123.56
Jane    11  2010    75.82
Jane    12  2010    12.45
Derek   1   2011    5.45
Derek   2   2011    10
Derek   3   2011    15
Derek   4   2011    30
Derek   5   2011    25
Derek   6   2011    11
Derek   7   2011    42
Derek   8   2011    48
Derek   9   2011    31
Derek   10  2011    23.89
Derek   11  2011    45.67
Derek   12  2011    38.89
Frank   1   2012    1
Frank   2   2012    2
Frank   3   2012    3
Frank   4   2012    4
Frank   5   2012    5
Frank   6   2012    6
Frank   7   2012    7
Frank   8   2012    8
Frank   9   2012    9
Frank   10  2012    10
Frank   11  2012    11
Frank   12  2012    12
```

Is it possible to get abbreviated month from just a number (1-12). I tried doing

```
d3.tsv("spending.tsv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) console.log(error)
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d3.time.format("%b").parse(d.mnum);
    });
});
```

but I got a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at e (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:15256)
at Function.t.parse (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:14782)
at http://localhost:8080/spending.html:56:26
```

How do I fix this?

How do I grab unique values for a select box? I don't want twelve of a name.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What exactly is line number 56 in `spending.html`. I think that's where the error stems for. Also what does "How do I grab unique values for a select box? I don't want twelve of a name." mean? You are selecting a person's name in the drop down right? Are you asking how to populate the dropdown with only one entry per person name from the `.tsv` file?

Comment: @VivekPradhan, line number 56 is "d3.time.format("%b").parse(d.mnum);" Yes, exactly. I want to know how to populate the dropdown with only one entry per person from the `.tsv` file. Also, is generating a heatmap possible from a dropdown selection?

Comment: So there are two questions here right? One is getting abbreviated month like `Jan` etc from month number and another is extracting unique person names from `.tsv` right?

Comment: Three, including the heatmap. But yes, two from the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the unique person names in an array through the loop you write in the question. Something like:

```
 var unique_names_arr = []; //Will contain unique names
 d3.tsv("spending.tsv", function(error, data) {
   if (error) console.log(error)
   data.forEach(function(d) {
     if (unique_names_arr.indexOf(data.name) === -1){
       //That means the name doesn't exist and we can push it into the array
         unique_names_arr.push(data.name);      
     };
   });
 });
```

The above snippet uses [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method to check if an element exists in an array.

Now to get abbreviated month names from numbers you can simply store all the abbreviated month names in an array:

```
 var abbrev_months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

 console.log(abbrev_months[d.mnum - 1]); //inside the loop
```

Basically Will `abbrev_months[d.mnum - 1]` will fetch 1st or 0'th index when `d.mnum` is 1 so it returns "Jan" for `d.mnum` to be 1 and so on.

Comment: I am having trouble with turning this into a heat map. Could I get some help doing that? I did not downvote the answer.

Comment: @V.Cruz, You do not mention what specific problems you face generating a heatMap. The two questions you raised are addressed in my response. The parse error and unique person names should be resolved now. You need to elaborate on what problems you are facing now in generating a HeatMap or better still, ask a new question.